# Get JSON tag with random name

Tags: java, json, path

I have this JSON:

```
{
   "-1":{          
      "name":"Ad hoc",
      "modifiedBy":"",          
      }
   },
   "9":{
      "name":"my name",
      "modifiedBy":"me",
      }
   }
}
```

The tags `"-1"` and `"9"` are IDs that I don't know.

I need get the tag `"9"` using the `"name"` `"my name"` with a JSON path.

How can I do that? I use Java.

Comment: Do you have a language preference? Also, that is invalid json

Comment: I'm usign java, bug the json path is standard, or not?

Comment: Well, yes, the path through the JSON would be standard, but different languages will get to that path by calling different functions and operators. So the language matters a lot for your question.

Comment: Were you thinking of JSONPath? JSONPath is a different thing than the JSON's path (which is what it looks like you're referring to). JSONPath is an emerging, open-source query language for JSON. And yes, it's syntax is universal regardless of the general-purpose language being used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming the JSON in your question is in Java's `JSONObject` form. Let's call this object `myjson`. Let's also say you are trying to get the ID of the sub-object that has an internal "name" value of "Ad hoc":

```
String nameKey = "Ad hoc";
String theID = "";
Set keys = myjson.keySet();
Iterator iter = keys.iterator();
while(iter.hasNext()) {
    String key = (String)iter.next();
    String name = (String)jsonObject.getJSONObject(key).get("name");
    if (name.equals(nameKey)) {
        theID = key;
    }
}
```

The variable `theID` should now contain the ID you want. If no match is found, `theID` will be an empty string.